# Qt-Creator fails to parse generic Qt-project but includes are OK

Tags: c++, qt, parsing, qt5, qt-creator

I imported an existing generic project which uses Qt and added all the Qt header paths to the .includes file.

The parser finds the includes but as soon anything Qt related is done, the parser complains about issues I've never seen before.

The code compiles w/o problems on the console.

Among the errors reported by qt creator are  following messages:

```
* no member named 'qMakeForeachContainer' in namespace 'QtPrivate'
```

*??? why so*

```
* unknown type name 'QComboBox'
```

*but include  is given an found*

```
* type 'QObject' is not a direct or virtual base of '...'
```

*'QObject' actually IS a direct base ...*

So what is broken here ? This happens on an newly installed 64bit system with imported generic project (not created as Qt project from within Qt Creator).

This always worked before :-/

Comment: Using Qt version 5.12

Comment: Did you try a `qmake` or build the project ?

Comment: The project builds w/o problems. But this is just using Qt creator as code editor.

Answer (score 0):

**Kind of Solved**: The reason for this is still not clear. For me it seems to work now by using the older Qt Creator that comes with my distribution (based on Qt 5.6). It is able to open and parse correctly the projects created by the not working Qt Creator (based on Qt 5.12) that comes with the downloaded and installed Qt 5.12. The '.includes' file is identical and uses the downloaded Qt 5.12 header files.

**Still longing for an explanation ...**